# To "Please" or "not to Please"

Tags: word-choice, appropriate

I'm writing the text for the order form of the website. The users are suppose to select their preferences with regard to ads and banners which they want to publish on the website.

My question is about the word "Please" when guiding the user through the order process. I checked other websites and everyone is using it differently. Should I or shouldn't I use for each step "Please" within the text?

Example:

1. Step 1. "Please" select one of the [...]
2. Step 2. "Please" select the menu language [...]

or would it be enough to go for :

1. Step 1. Select one of the [...]
2. Step 2. Select menu language

I don't want that it sounds like an order to the users but can't "feel" how it sounds for native English speaking users.

Comment: Don’t say *please*.

Comment: Teo, I agree with @tchrist, don't say "please" and, at the second step, don't say "pleaase", otherwise the user expects to read "pleaaase" at the third step, and so forth :)

Comment: @Carlo_R. lol! And then it just takes on a sense of pleading! :-D

Comment: @Carlo_R. Well, if that's what it takes to make them happy glaaaadly ;-)

Comment: Teo, +1 & lol & yup!

Comment: Please do not say *please*.  Thank you for not saying *thank you*.

Comment: By this reasoning, elevator buttons which say P1, P2, M, 2, 3, ... are rude. They should say "Please press this button if you wish to go to the second subterranean level of the parkade", et cetera.

Comment: Oh, ***purrrrlease!*** This is just POB.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for writing advice. Please see our [help].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends.  In my opinion unless you're talking about some kind of delay, skip it.  Americans may often find it condescending or superfluous.

The only place I'd see it being beneficial is if you're asking them to wait for something.

Example: Please wait 24 hours while we process your paperwork.

Comment: Jacob, intersting & +1, but how can "Please" be interpreted in "Please, wait *2400* hours while we process your paperwork"?

Comment: @Carlo_R: I don't really understand your question.  I didn't mean 2400 hours.  In the US it's really common to say that something will be done in 24-72 hours meaning 1-3 days from the given submission time.

"Please" is often used here because people are impatient and we think of computers as being immediate.  Using the word please adds a human element to it and makes people feel like even though they have to wait they're still valued/it will happen.

Comment: Jacob, thank you for so a great explanation, but so, if you have more than 72 hours to wait, is not it better to drop the "Please"? Pardon for my *Inglish* (=Italian English)!

Comment: @Carlo_R: No, I was just saying that those were very common examples.  I would say a good rule would be to add Please anytime the user has to wait for something for any length of time. 

Example:  Please be patient while we analyse you application.  This could take 1-2 weeks. 

It's not really the timeframe that's important, it's the acknowledgement of their patience.  The timeframe is usually for your benefit as it keeps people from constantly bothering you for updates and calms their nerves.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: Jacob, yes, you have been very kind to answer my comments, thank you and stay with us. We are a great community where it make sense to stay.

Comment: Carlo, So far I really like the site and definitely plan to stay around.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not using “Please” if your form comprises multiple steps. For example, it would be a bit awkward if your order process looked like this:

1. Please select a menu language
2. Please select an appetizer
3. Please select an entrée

It may be preferable to instead use different verbs for each step, thereby toning down the repetitiveness:

1. Select a menu language
2. Choose an appetizer
3. Pick an entrée

Answer (score 0):

I agree in general with the comments and with the two previous answers. The only additional qualification I would make it that it may depend on your expected primary audience.

I certainly would not include "Please" for European or N. American audiences.

I am aware, however, that in some Asian cultures 'formal politeness' is much more common and its omission may seem blunt or even rude. So I would qualify the advice to omit "please", by suggesting that if your intended or expected audience is primarily worldwide, European or N. American, then, yes, omit "please". If your expected audience is primarily an Asian culture, then you should perhaps consider what is expected by your audience.

In any case, you ought to be able to have made a judgment on this issue yourself simply by looking at other comparable websites!

Comment: Right. That’s why you see all those Asian web pages with their `Please Submit` and `Please Enter` and `Please Save Edits` and `Please Cancel` and `Please Send` and `Please Contact Us` and `Please Mail` and `Please About` and `Please OK` and `Please Yourself` buttons. :)